# MEDIA_URL not displaying PDF links

Tags: python, html, django

There are pdfs in my media folder, but this won't display them in my HTML. I've checked other posts, but nothing works

```
 <h1 class="my-4">Batch Records</h1>
      <div class="row">
        {% if MEDIA_URL%}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-4">
                  <p>Uploaded to:<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}">{{ MEDIA_URL }}</a></p>
                  <a class="btn btn-dark my-4" href="/">Return to Homepage</a>
        {% else %}
        <p>No records added.</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
```

SETTINGS.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

VIEWS.py

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['upload']:
    upload = request.FILES['upload']
    fss = FileSystemStorage()
    file = fss.save(upload.name, upload)
    file_url = fss.url(file)
    return render(request, 'website/upload.html', {'file_url': file_url})
return render(request, 'website/upload.html')
```

URLS.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from inventory import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    
    path("br", views.upload, name="upload")

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Clicking on Uploaded to:{{ MEDIA_URL }} tries to take me to a different html template, not my media folder.

Comment: Huh, well I'm trying to reference the django media directory and thought MEDIA_URL = '/media/' would link to that directory

Comment: Could you post an example of how to write and iterate through a file path?

Answer (score 1):

Had to add 'django.template.context_processors.media' in the 'context_processors' option of TEMPLATES.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
```

]